# Javascript foo = foo.bar = foobar

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty confused by something I encountered in an application I'm working in.

There is a method in my object, called `move` which does this (simplified) upon clicking a list item.

```
var board = {
  move: function() {
     var unique_id = Puzzle.pieces.id = 28;
     // More stuff going on with the unique_id variable.
  },
}
```

Then throughout the application, Puzzle.pieces.id gets used to assign ids to other stuff like this:

```
$('#puzzle-piece-' + Puzzle.pieces.id + '');
```

After thinking about it might be doing for a while, I came with the following:
*Upon invoking the method, `unique_id` assigns a temporary property to the pieces object in the Puzzle namespace object.* Then when clicking a new list item, the the property get overwritten with a new value.

If this is correct, is it a common practise to quickly make a temporary value available throughout an application, if not, what does it really do?

Comment: It might seem useful to add temporary properties to objects and delete them later after you don't need them anymore. But this is a bad practice because it can greatly degrade performance.

Comment: What temporary property? All I see is a local variable. Did you read the answers, perchance?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the local variable `unique_id` is most likely there only as an efficiency measure. The method could probably be rewritten to dispense with the local variable and use `Puzzle.pieces.id` everywhere that it uses `unique_id`; however that would require two property look-ups for every value access. (It's also a bit strange to have a hard-coded value stored in a variable named `unique_id`. When every function call assigns the same value, it's hard to see what's unique about it.)

Comment: @underscore_d - How could OP have read the answers before posting the question?

Comment: I was talking to @sam100rav. I assumed context would make that clear. Perhaps I should have explicitly addressed my comment to them. (I'd tag you, too, but 1 per post, so...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

```
 var unique_id = Puzzle.pieces.id = 28;
```

does exactly the same thing as these:

```
 var unique_id;
 Puzzle.pieces.id = 28;
 unique_id = Puzzle.pieces.id;
```

So, it assigns `28` to that "id" property of the `Puzzle.pieces` object, and then it assigns that value to the local variable `unique_id`. The important things to note are that the assignment to the "id" property happens *before* the assignment to the local variable, and that the "id" property really doesn't have much to do with the local variable other than as the source of its value. The two are independent otherwise, and either can change afterwards without affecting the other.

There's nothing temporary about that "id" property. If it already existed, it's given a new value by that code. If it didn't exist, then it's created. In either case the property will stick around until it's explicitly deleted.

*edit* — it's correctly pointed out in a comment that the `Puzzle.pieces` object could have a setter function defined for the "id" property, meaning that the value of the property may not be `28`. Thus, the *real* equivalent is

```
 var unique_id;
 Puzzle.pieces.id = 28;
 unique_id = 28;
```

The initialization

```
var unique_id = Puzzle.pieces.id = 28;
```

is parsed as

```
var unique_id = (Puzzle.pieces.id = 28);
```

and the value of the right-hand side of the outer `=` will always be `28`.

Comment: I'm not sure that the two pieces of code are equivalent. If `Puzzle.pieces.id` has a setter and/or getter, then the results could be quite different in the second case than in the first. (In the first case, the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1) says that the value of an assignment expression is the right-hand value [regardless of what getter/setter mechanism, if any, is involved in setting the left-hand value].)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for writhing that out. I've been testing by loggin the object to console before and after creating the property, and it's all clear now. The part about temporary was confusing from my side, I really meant that it's only there until the client refreshes, but that's _obviously_ where programs default back :)

Comment: @TedHopp in the presence of setter/getter functions, you're right; the property might do anything. And you're right that the value of the assignment expression will always be the assigned value, and not the result of calling the getter. I'll update the answer. (It's doubtful that that was happening in the code in the OP, but it's true nevertheless.)

Comment: Still wonder though, is this common in programs, or bad practise ( ignoring the performance part of it ). What would another approach be to make a value available across different files without creating global variables? A modular pattern maybe?

Comment: I agree -- it's unlikely that anything like getter/setter is involved. (BTW, your answer had a +1 from me. I have no idea why it would be downvoted.)

Comment: @piggypig it's really a fairly normal thing to do. Whether it's "bad" or "good" really depends on the surrounding code, but there's nothing inherently wrong or ugly about it.

Comment: Thanks guys, got everything I asked for, enjoying the discussion though :)

Answer (score 1):

`var unique_id = Puzzle.pieces.id = 28;`

means

`Set Puzzle.pieces.id to 28. The act of setting it returns 28. Set unique_id to that return value.`

Answer (score 1):

```
var unique_id = Puzzle.pieces.id = 28;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Puzzle.pieces.id = 28;
var unique_id = Puzzle.pieces.id;
```

There are a couple of benefits to holding a reference to the id in a local variable, firstly it's just easier to type `unique_id` vs `Puzzle.pieces.id` and secondly it allows minifiers to achieve a higher compression ratio as it can safely reduce `unique_id` into, for example, `a`.

As per comments, it's more correctly the equivalent to:

```
var unique_id = 28;    
Puzzle.pieces.id = 28;
```

Comment: It's also more efficient, since accessing a local variable value is a lot less work than two property look-ups.

Comment: Would `id` be assigned by reference, though, or would it be copied? I know objects are assigned by reference, but not primitives. I guess we don't really know without seeing the declaration.

Comment: @underscore_d - `id` is not assigned to `unique_id` at all. The value that results from evaluating the assignment expression `Puzzle.pieces.id = 28` is what is assigned to `unique_id`. That value is, according to the spec, the right-hand value of the assignment itself (that is, 28).

Comment: @riscarrott might want to edit their post, in that case. Thanks for confirming what I suspected

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought about the reference part. It's definitely easier to type and maintain.

Comment: By my understanding, there is no reference involved here, if we're using the proper definition of that word.

Comment: @TedHopp Cool, it indeed doesn't lookup the prototype chain everytime I use it.

Answer (score -2):

If you set unique_id to 28 directly, it would probably become an integer. If pieces.id is not an integer, then unique_id may end up as some other type.

Comment: This applies everywhere in weakly typed languages like JS. Pointing out a truism like this does nothing to answer the specific question being asked.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Variables and object properties have no inherent type in javascript, and what this answer says may happen will in fact *never* happen.